# "OR" operator not working in beanshell assertion

Tags: jmeter

During my test, the http response code in the sampler may be `201` or `304`. For assertion I ma using beanshell assertion with the following code and it is not working, what I am missing here.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;
String failureMessage = "";
String ResCode = SampleResult.getResponseCode();

try {
    if (!ResCode.equals("304") || !ResCode.equals("201")) {
    failureMessage = "Got Response Code" + ResCode;
        AssertionResult result = new AssertionResult("Expected Response 304");
        result.setFailure(true);
        result.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
        prev.addAssertionResult(result);
        prev.setSuccessful(false);
        SampleResult.setStartNextThreadLoop(true);
} 
    else {

    }
}

catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no number for which it is true that the number equals 304 and equals 201 at the same time.

Therefore, at least one of the operands of `||` is always true for any possible value of `ResCode`.   If `ResCode` is 304, the right-hand operand is true.  If `ResCode` is 201, the left-hand operand is true.  For any other number, both operands are true.

```
(!ResCode.equals("304") || !ResCode.equals("201"))
```

Therefore the result of `||` is always true.

You want

```
(!ResCode.equals("304") && !ResCode.equals("201"))
```

or equivalently

```
(!(ResCode.equals("304") || ResCode.equals("201")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong operator, you need to amend your condition as:

```
if (!ResCode.equals("201") && !ResCode.equals("304")) {
```

In general there is no need of any scripting, you can achieve the same using normal [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion):

[image]

However if you need to implement more complex custom logic afterwards be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for performance reasons so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)